# Get raw touch data from display into RPI zero

Tags: pi-zero, display, touchscreen

I am using 7Inch HDMI Touch Display with RPI zero.

I want to pass the pixel data ( or anything else related ) where touch is sensed to another device.

I could not find related information.

Is it even possible ? Any blog or something will do too.
Thank you.

Comment: what is the actual problem? ... you described three or more separate, unrelated functions in your question

Comment: I just want touch pixels, where user touched.

Comment: so, what is stopping you?

Comment: I could not find how to do that. One way I get this is by using GUI. When you touch anywhere it just give you mouser poiter data. But how to get raw data directly from display ?

Comment: Mouse* pointer* I mean sorry for this

Answer (score 1):

A touchscreen has no relation to the display it is attached to, and has no concept of pixels. Its driver receives analog signals from the matrix and produces X and Y coordinates which are float values between 0 and 1, and sometimes (depending on the device type and the driver) a byte encoding the pressure. If you know the underlying screen resolution, you can convert X and Y coordinates to pixels.

You can read "raw" touchscreen data using [`libinput`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXi/inputlib.html). You will get a new input event every time the coordinates (and the pressure) change.